# Is a language closed under string concatenation, repetition, and/or taking substring regular?

Tags: formal-languages, closure-properties

Is a language $L$ regular, context-free, context-sensitive, recursively enumerable, or ..., if 
$L$ is closed under

- string concatenation, and/or
- string repetition, and/or
- taking substring?

Somehow related but not identical to https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28534/what-are-the-formal-grammars-of-the-following-recursively-defined-formal-languag

Furthermore, the same question if $L$ further satisfies that every string of length 1 is also in $L$?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Also, you seem to be asking about 40 questions at the same time. Please focus on one.

Comment: @Raphael If you check his profile you will see that he ask lots of questions on other sites as well. I don't know if this is a good thing or a bad thing as they seem to be the kind of basic questions other might ask but are afraid too. The thing I could not figure out is what is his over-all goal?

Comment: What is your over-all goal with all of these questions? I see that you have been asking them for a few years. I too am a self-learner so I can see why you ask them.

Comment: @GuyCoder: What worries me is that the questions improve neither in terms of basic CS ability nor in terms of "using SE correctly".

Comment: @GuyCoder: As a self learner at your age, you are an inspiration to me

Comment: I use to ask lots of questions also, and many of them were closed. I now do much more research before asking a question but still at times have to ask the unspecific question. That is why I pointed you to [CiteseerX](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/index).

Comment: I don't think it's a good thing.  In this case, it's not just asking too many questions; it is asking too many *poorly-researched* questions.  Asking poorly-researched questions does not contribute to the goals of StackExchange and feels a bit selfish to me; if everyone did this, I suspect many experts would leave.  In this case I think Tim needs to spend some quality time with a few textbooks.  The ability to ask questions that reach such a broad audience of expert computer scientists is a precious resource; asking many poorly researched questions might not be what we want to encourage.

Comment: By the way, if you have to ask this many questions, I wouldn't  call it self-learning any more.  Self-learning is sitting down with a bunch of textbooks and learning it on your own.  Asking lots of questions without much sign of self-effort is closer to asking for unpaid tutoring...

Comment: @D.W.: In my view your attitude is a bad thing. You can't define "well-researched" objectively. If all you want is every asker here give in to your not so "friendly" comment, I suspect it is not so difficult to pretend to add lot of little relevant stuffs to clutter questions, for the sake of showing "I have researched". If everyone is like you, I also suspect many newbies will not dare to ask questions any more.

Comment: Tim, here is a good overview of [how much research is expected](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723).  P.S. If part of your question is answered on Wikipedia, then you almost certainly done far too little research.  (The same is true for standard textbooks.)  In this case the closure properties of regular languages, context-free languages, etc., are well-documented on Wikipedia, in textbooks, etc., so it is quite clear that you have not done as much research as you could have. (cont.)

Comment: Only if you claim that Wikipedia is always easy to understand.

Comment: You could have started by filling in a table of all combinations of closure properties (along the columns) and different kinds of languages (along the rows) and filled in what you know and asked about the ones where you weren't able to find information.  (And you could have told us where you had looked to find that information.)  That would have required more effort before asking, though.

Comment: Let me just gently suggest that if your problem is that you read the Wikipedia article but didn't understand it then you should be mentioning that in your question, explaining precisely what you didn't understand about the Wikipedia article, and explaining what you did to try to resolve your confusion -- did you try reading other textbooks? which ones? can you pinpoint more precisely what you don't understand?  You haven't done any of that in this question.

Comment: Tim, the attitude is not helping. Keep in mind that it's *you* asking for help here; all users spend their free-time on answering questions here, without compensation. But as I said, your ongoing refusal to adhere to SE standards and policies (ask *one* reasonable scoped question per post; do some research and explain what you did/tried) worries me more. "Slow self-learner" is not an excuse for laziness. Note that "consistently low quality" can even be a reason for suspension!
<mod>Everybody, please take extended discussions to [chat].</mod>

Answer (score 6):

Considering how much you have been learning so far, you should try
answering some questions by yourself.

For example, quite trivially, a language closed under string
concatenation and "taking substring" is regular. The reason is that
only two language have both closure properties: $\Sigma^*$ and
$\emptyset$.

Actually, I guess the empty set is closed under a lot of operations,
since there are no strings to operate upon.

Given any non-empty language, if it is closed under "taking
substring", all strings of length 1 are in the language (assuming the
alphabet is restricted to what is actually used). And if it is closed
under string concatenation, you can concatenate any number of these
strings of length 1 in any order, thus producing any word in
$\Sigma^*$.

But your question is just too many questions, which is not customary
on this site, even if there is some flexibility.